# angular 8: single ng-container for multiple view child references

Tags: angular, dom, viewchild, ng-container

I have three viewchild decorators  in my component like this:

```
@ViewChild('propertiesPage1', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) propertiesPage11: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('propertiesPage2', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) propertiesPage22: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('propertiesPage3', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) propertiesPage33: ViewContainerRef;
```

The references of these are provided in the my html file like this:

```
<div>
  <ng-container #propertiesPage1>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<div>
  <ng-container #propertiesPage2>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<div>
  <ng-container #propertiesPage3>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

I want to merge all the three containers into single one and that ng-container should contain reference only to the viewchild which has changed recently.
Something like this:

```
<div>
  <ng-container #propertiesPage>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ViewChild` decorator is only for one child. To get array of children you need to use `@ViewChildren`

Try like this:

```
 @ViewChildren('propertiesPage') pages: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>
```